# Speed up LEFT OUTER JOIN query in Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

The question is for Firebird 2.5. Let's assume we have the following query:

```sql
SELECT  
 EVENTS.ID,  
 EVENTS.TS,  
 EVENTS.DEV_TS,  
 EVENTS.COMPLETE_TS,  
 EVENTS.OBJ_ID,  
 EVENTS.OBJ_CODE,  
 EVENTS.SIGNAL_CODE,  
 EVENTS.SIGNAL_EVENT,  
 EVENTS.REACTION,  
 EVENTS.PROT_TYPE,  
 EVENTS.GROUP_CODE,  
 EVENTS.DEV_TYPE,  
 EVENTS.DEV_CODE,  
 EVENTS.SIGNAL_LEVEL,  
 EVENTS.SIGNAL_INFO,  
 EVENTS.USER_ID,  
 EVENTS.MEDIA_ID,  
 SIGNALS.ID AS SIGNAL_ID,  
 SIGNALS.SIGNAL_TYPE,  
 SIGNALS.IMAGE AS SIGNAL_IMAGE,  
 SIGNALS.NAME AS SIGNAL_NAME,  
 REACTION.INFO,   
 USERS.NAME AS USER_NAME 
FROM EVENTS 
LEFT OUTER JOIN SIGNALS ON (EVENTS.SIGNAL_ID = SIGNALS.ID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN REACTION ON (EVENTS.ID = REACTION.EVENTS_ID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN USERS ON (EVENTS.USER_ID = USERS.ID) 
WHERE (TS BETWEEN '27.07.2021 00:00:00' AND '28.07.2021 10:34:08') 
 AND (OBJ_ID = 8973)
 AND (DEV_CODE IN (0, 1234))
 AND (DEV_TYPE  = 79)
 AND (PROT_TYPE  = 8)
ORDER BY TS;
```

`EVENTS` has about 190 million records by now and this query takes too much time to complete. As I read [here](https://use-the-index-luke.com/), the tables have to have indexes on all the columns that are used.

Here are the `CREATE INDEX` statements for the `EVENTS` table:

```
CREATE INDEX FK_EVENTS_OBJ ON EVENTS (OBJ_ID);
CREATE INDEX FK_EVENTS_SIGNALS ON EVENTS (SIGNAL_ID);
CREATE INDEX IDX_EVENTS_COMPLETE_TS ON EVENTS (COMPLETE_TS);
CREATE INDEX IDX_EVENTS_OBJ_SIGNAL_TS ON EVENTS (OBJ_ID,SIGNAL_ID,TS);
CREATE INDEX IDX_EVENTS_TS ON EVENTS (TS);
```

Here is the data from the PLAN analyzer:

```
PLAN JOIN (JOIN (JOIN (EVENTS ORDER IDX_EVENTS_TS INDEX (FK_EVENTS_OBJ, IDX_EVENTS_TS), SIGNALS INDEX (PK_SIGNALS)), REACTION INDEX (IDX_REACTION_EVENTS)), USERS INDEX (PK_USERS))
```

As requested the speed of the execution:

```
without LEFT JOIN -> 138ms 
with LEFT JOIN ->  338ms
```

Is there another way to speed up the execution of the query besides indexing the columns or maybe add another index?

If I add another index will the optimizer choose to use it?

Comment: If your database structure uses primary key, unique keys and foreign keys, you don't need to create extra indexes for those columns: indexes are created automatically for those constraints.

Comment: `DEV_CODE IN (0, 1234)` - is this a real query and this condition never changes, or do real queries have many more numbers in that list ?

Comment: @Arioch'The Yes it is real. The `1234` is what changes whenever another device with different `DEV_CODE` is selected from the frontend.

Answer (score 2):

You can only optimize the joins themselves by being sure that the keys are indexed in the *second* tables.  These all look like primary keys, so they should have appropriate indexes.

For this `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE TS BETWEEN '27.07.2021 00:00:00' AND '28.07.2021 10:34:08') 
      OBJ_ID = 8973 AND
      DEV_CODE IN (0, 1234) AND
      DEV_TYPE  = 79 AND
      PROT_TYPE  = 8
```

You probably want an index on `(OBJ_ID, DEV_TYPE, PROT_TYPE, TS, DEV_CODE)`.  The order of the first three keys is not particularly important because they are all equality comparisons.  I am guessing that one day of data is fewer rows than two device codes.

Comment: Your guess about the volume of data is correct. As for the `Primary keys` the only one that is not is `REACTION.EVENTS_ID` but it has an index.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you want to find the table1 rows quickly. You are using several columns in your `WHERE` clause to get them. Provide an index on these columns. Which column is the most selective? I.e. which criteria narrows the result rows most? Let's say it's `dt`, so we put this first:

```
create index idx1 on table1 (dt, oid, pt, ts, dc);
```

I have put `ts` and `dt` last, because we are looking for more than one value in these columns. It may still be that putting `ts` or `ds`as the first column is a good choice. Sometimes we have to play around with this. I.e. provide several indexes with the column order changed and then see which one gets used by the DBMS.

Tables table2 and tabe4 get accessed by the primary key for which exists an index. But table3 gets accessed by `t1id`. So provide an index on that, too:

```
create index idx2 on table3 (t1id);
```